# htaccess Rewrite rule for accessing without php extension causes error on trailing slash

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

This is my current rewrite rule for accessing php files without extension.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

However, I want to be able to format a URL like so,

```
https://example.com/somefile/parameter
```

So, something like,

```
https://example.com/check_user/12345
```

However I get 500 Internal Server Error when there is trailing parameter after the slash(/).

I really want to get to the bottom of this rewrite rule, and conquer it, but I simply don't have the time to do so. (Pressed for production.)

I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: I don't have any other rules except for 404 redirect rule.
The example URL: https://example.com/somefile/parameter will cause the error. While https://example.com/somefile/ doesn't. somefile in this case is a php file, somefile.php

Comment: btw, https://example.com/somefile.php/parameter works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seemed to have fixed it by using this.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
```

Got it here.
[Remove .php extension with .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/remove-php-extension-with-htaccess)